# Is it possible to use session.insert for one to main relationships in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have read in the following link:
[Sqlalchemy adding multiple records and potential constraint violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591972/sqlalchemy-adding-multiple-records-and-potential-constraint-violation)

That using  SQLAlchemy core library to perform the inserts is much faster option, rather than the ORM's session.add() method:

i.e:

```
session.add()
```

should be replaced with:

```
session.execute(Entry.__table__.insert(), params=inserts)
```

In the following code I have tried to replace .*add* with .*insert*:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, String, Integer, ForeignKey, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    # Use default=func.now() to set the default hiring time
    # of an Employee to be the current time when an
    # Employee record was created
    hired_on = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    department_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('department.id'))
    # Use cascade='delete,all' to propagate the deletion of a Department onto its Employees
    department = relationship(
        Department,
        backref=backref('employees',
                        uselist=True,
                        cascade='delete,all'))


from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgres://blah:blah@blah:blah/blah')

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

d = Department(name="IT")
emp1 = Employee(name="John", department=d)
s = session()
s.add(d)
s.add(emp1)
s.commit() 


s.delete(d)  # Deleting the department also deletes all of its employees.
s.commit()
s.query(Employee).all()
```

**# Insert Option Attempt**

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
d = insert(Department).values(name="IT")
d1 = d.on_conflict_do_nothing()
s.execute(d1)
emp1 = insert(Employee).values(name="John", department=d1)
emp1 = emp1.on_conflict_do_nothing()
s.execute(emp1)
```

The error I receive:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: department
```

I can't quite understand the syntax and how to do it in the right way, I'm new to the SQLAlchemy.

It looks my question is similar to [How to get primary key columns in pd.DataFrame.to_sql insertion method for PostgreSQL "upsert"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306417/how-to-get-primary-key-columns-in-pd-dataframe-to-sql-insertion-method-for-postg/57307856#57307856)
, so potentially by answering either of our questions, you could help two people at the same time ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to SQLAlchemy as well, but this is what I found :

Using your exact code, adding department only didn't work using "s.execute(d1)", so I changed it to the below and it does work :

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
        d = insert(Department).values(name="IT")
        d1 = d.on_conflict_do_nothing()
        conn.execute(d1)
```

I found on SQLAlchemy documentation that in the past it was just a warning when you try to use a virtual column that doesn't really exist. But from version 0.8, it has been changed to an exception.

[image]

As a result, I am not sure if you can do that using the insert. I think that SQLAlchemy does it behind the scene in some other way when using session.add(). Maybe some experts can elaborate here.

I hope that will help.